# SQL and storing foreign keys on multiple tables vs joining through tables for queries

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys

What's best practice for querying multiple tables and foreign keys?

For instance:

User has many Tasks has many Reminders

I would assume best practice would be to keep foreign keys to their direct relatives, ie:

tasks table:
id, user_id

reminders table:
id, task_id

...to avoid situations where you have a bunch of foreign keys connecting tables to all possible relatives.

Let's say I want to retrieve all of a user's reminders.

```
SELECT reminders.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN tasks ON users.id = tasks.user_id
LEFT JOIN reminders ON tasks.id = reminders.task_id
WHERE tasks.user_id = {#YourUserIdVariable}
```

Is there a point at which doing joins to retrieve a record outweighs the integrity of the db? (assuming that storing reminders.user_id would be a bad practive in the first place?

5 tables? 10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it better to store redundant information or join tables when necessary in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237033/is-it-better-to-store-redundant-information-or-join-tables-when-necessary-in-mys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much data do you expect to store in your database? If there are relatively small amount of rows in each table for the joins the execution time between a normalized and non-normalized database will be negligible.

So instead just go with a design that makes sense to you and you can normalize and de-normalize tables where it makes sense.

Here's a good read on the subject:http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html

Comment: link doesnt works

Answer (score 2):

The standard is not to store unecessarily redundant information, *including* redundant Foreign Key information that could be derived through relations/joins.

In practice this means, storing only the direct relationships' FKeys, and not secondary or implicit FKey info.  For performance reasons you may at some point decide to try "short-circuiting" a relation, but technically that's a form of de-normalization.  You can do it, but you only *should* do it when the need is apparent, in other words, proper normalization should always be the default, anything else needs to significantly justify itself.

As for "*Is there a point at which doing joins to retrieve a record outweighs the integrity of the db?*": Possibly, but this can only be determined on a case-by-case basis.  It's not possible to reduce a business trade-off like this to a data-only technical rule.